# Computing functions over multiple lists

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I need to produce a list containing the averages of a lists of lists where the number of sub-lists could vary.  So given the input list:

```
((l1a l1b l1c) (l2a l2b l2c) (l3a l3b l3c)...)
```

the output would be:

```
(average(l1a l2a l3a) average(l1b l2b l3b) average(l1c l2c l3c)...).
```

I'm sure there's a really elegant way to do this in lisp but I don't know where to start.  Any advice would be gratefully received.

Comment: It looks like you just need to `map`. I don't know CL, but I do know Clojure, which is another lisp. If your lists are bound to a symbol `lists`, you'd just do, in Clojure, `(map average lists)`. I'm sure it's very similar in CL.

Comment: That's it! Thank you. I knew there would be an easy way but wasn't aware of the map function.  In CL to do that using add for example you would simply use: (map 'list #'+ '(1 2 3) '(1 2 3) '(1 2 3))

Comment: Np. And if you're just starting into functional programming, make sure you have a very good understanding of `map` and `reduce`/`fold` (I don't know what CL calls it). Those are bread-and-butter functions that you'll likely be using regularly.

Comment: Carcinegate is correct. You need to define an average function that takes a list as a parameter then pass it to mapcar . The syntax is different from Clojure - use (mapcar #'average list)  where average is the function you define. The average function should use reduce to sum the list.

Comment: Got it - thank you. (defun average (lst) (/ (reduce #'+ lst) (length lst))) and then (mapcar #'average '((50 23 35) (60 12 34) (70 52 38)))

Comment: @peebz: no, that computes the averages of the sublists, but not what you have described in your question. There the averages are computed not by sublists, but iteratively over the elements of the sublists: all firsts, then all second, ...

Comment: oopps - my bad. sorry about that

Answer (score 6):

```
CL-USER 27 > (let* ((list-of-lists '((1.0 2.0 3.0)
                                     (1.0 3.0 5.0)
                                     (1.0 4.0 6.0)
                                     (1.0 5.0 8.0)))
                    (length (length list-of-lists)))
               (mapcar (lambda (x)
                         (/ x length))
                       (reduce (lambda (l1 l2)
                                 (mapcar #'+ l1 l2))
                               list-of-lists)))
(1.0 3.5 5.5)
```

Comment: Yes, I realised it was wrong when I just tried to apply my solution to my problem. Many thanks for your solution Rainer.